# Как компилятор определяет реализацию функции?

Tags: c++

Есть два файла. Оба лежат в корневой папке. Первый:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void g();

int main()
{
    g();
}
```

Второй:

```
void g() {

    cout << 4;
}
```

Собственно почему функция g() вызвалась в main(). Изначально я думал что главная функция сможет узнать о реализации g() только если прописать `#include "add.cpp"` но на сайте на котором я учусь говорится что лучше не писать эту строчку и использовать код который я привел выше. Получается компилятор автоматически проверяет реализацию в файлах лежащих в корне?

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальное толковое название плиз.

Comment: Покажите, как вы компилируете этот код

Comment: У вас в настройках проекта где-то должен быть список .cpp файлов. Компилятор не берет все .cpp из одной папки без разбора, а только те, которые указаны в проекте.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что "компилятор автоматически проверяет реализацию в файлах лежащих в корне"? Откуда взялась такая идея?

Answer (score 2):

Ваша программа состоит из двух отдельных файлов реализации (`.cpp` файлов), которые *вместе* были *явно* направлены на вход транслятору С++. Транслятор С++ не занимается никакой "автоматической проверкой файлов, лежащих в корне". Транслятор работает только с файлами, явно переданными ему на вход в качестве входных параметров. Именно это и было сделано в вашем случае.

Одна из компонент этого транслятора - линкер, компоновщик, редактор связей - как раз и занимается тем, что выполняет поиск и связывает вызовы функций, сделанные в одних файлах, с определениями этих функций, сделанными в других файлах. Это и произошло в вашем случае. Опять же, линкер работает только с файлами, явно переданными ему на вход в качестве параметров.

Такое связывание вызовов между файлами возможно только для функций с *внешним связыванием*. Ваша функция `g()` как раз является таковой.

Comment: Спасибо, но что значит "явно направлены на вход транслятору"? Я вроде бы ничего не прописывал.

Comment: @midia Вы работаете в Visual Studio? Если так, то в Visual Studio у вас есть *проект*, в котором и указаны явным образом все файлы, входящие в вашу программу.